# Non-separability of the Cadlag functions equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compacts

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Consider the space $D:=D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^N)$ of component-wise right continuous functions with left limits. Endow $D$ with the metric $$d(\psi,\tilde{\psi}):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}||\psi-\tilde{\psi}||_{[0,n]}\wedge1$$
where $||\psi-\tilde{\psi}||_{[0,n]}:=\sup_{t\in[0,n]}|\psi(t)-\tilde{\psi}(t)|$. How can we deduce that $(D,d)$ is not a separable metric space?

If we take $e\in S^{N-1}$, a unit vector on the sphere, and set $\psi_t(\tau)=\mathbf{1}_{[t,\infty)}e$ for $t\in[0,1]$, then if we can show that $||\psi_t-\psi_s||_{[0,1]}=1$ for all $t\neq s$ where $s,t\in[0,1]$, then this could mean that there is no countable dense subset in $D$. However, I am unsure as to how to complete the argument.